# insert select with if else condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have 2 tables, table1 and table2, and I am  using

```
insert into table1 
(  Col1,
   Col2,
   Col3
) 

select 
(  ColA,
   ColB,
   ColC
)
from 
table2
```

but the logic between Col3 and ColC is this:

```
if ColC = 'A' then Col3 = Y
else Col3 = N
```

What's the SQL for this, I am using SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
insert into table1 
(  Col1,
   Col2,
   Col3
) 

select 
   ColA,
   ColB,
   case when ColC = 'A' then 'Y' else 'N' end
   -- alternatively:
   -- case ColC when 'A' then 'Y' else 'N' end
from 
table2
```

Comment: Could also use the alternate case syntax here which is marginally more concise.  "case ColC when 'A' then 'Y' else 'N' end".  Not a big deal but just thought I'd point it out.

Comment: Brandon, What is alternate case syntax. I am kind new to sql server. Thanks.